# Android OpenGL game code execution

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing a card game with OpenGL ES 1.0 in android.. I've two class, GameRenderer and GameLogic. When I give the cards to the players in GameLogic, I set variables in GameLogic that onDrawFrame use for animation.. So, I need to stop the code in GameLogic until animation finish. This is the problem.. How stop code execution?

Comment: For future reference: OpenGL 1.0 is something completely different, it is over 20 years old and nobody uses it! You are using OpenGL **ES** 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to restructure the architecture of your application. Instead of reading data out of the GameLogic class, you need to have your GameLogic class modify some sort of GameData object. Once the data is saved in the GameData object, you have it send a notification or message to your GameRenderer that the data has changed. The GameRenderer can then read the new data and act accordingly.

This is a standard design pattern, called [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: Thank you.. In GameLogic there are data that GameRender use to update the screen.. So, when I call my function to give the cards to the players, I need to do the animation first and than update data for the screen..

Comment: Your question is very difficult to answer, because there are so few details (which is why it was downvoted by several people). Additionally, this forum is not a very good one for asking architecture/design style questions. You would get a better response, and more answers if you had posted a very lengthy question detailing what you're trying to do (are you doing a standard playing card game, or a battle card game, or something else?), and had code snippets for the portions you're trying to get answers on. As it is, all I can say is do more research.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do animation before instructions that updates game data.. After tests for animations (how many cards, ...), if I use Thread.sleep, the main anctivity stops so also the opengl render..

Comment: Solved with a new thread! That is, I've a GameRender and a GameLogic. With Thread.sleep in GameLogic for waiting OpenGL animation, all the game lock. To avoid this, game code with animation and wait, starts in a new thread, so in this I can use thread.sleep until animation ends (with a boolean as flag).